# Sorting in edittext

Tags: java, android

I want to search for actors but I'm getting this error. I made it before but, now I'm trying a different adapter. It's probably so basic, but I couldnt fixed it. Please Help. Thanks.

```
public class Actors extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.movie_list);

        ArrayList<Actor> actors = new ArrayList<Actor>();

        actors.add(new Actor("jacknicholson",1,R.drawable.jacknicholson));
        actors.add(new Actor("Marlon Brando",2,R.drawable.marlonbrando));
        actors.add(new Actor("Robert De Niro",3,R.drawable.robertdeniro));
        actors.add(new Actor("Al Pacino",4,R.drawable.alpacino));
        actors.add(new Actor("Danel Day-Lewis",5,R.drawable.danielday));
        actors.add(new Actor("Dustin Hoffman",6,R.drawable.dustinhoffman));


        final MovieAdapter itemsAdapter = new MovieAdapter(this, actors);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);


        EditText theFilter =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editt);

        theFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                 //Here I'm getting an error
                (Actors.this).itemsAdapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Here is my movie adapter. In Actors class I can't use (Actors.this). I can't use it as `itemsAdapter.getFilter().filter(char)`, but with this way it doesn't find anything.

```
public class MovieAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Actor> {

    public MovieAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Actor> words) {

        super(context, 0, words);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        Actor currentWord = getItem(position);

        TextView songTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.Name_text_view);
        songTextView.setText((currentWord.getmPopularity()));

        final TextView singerTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.popularity_text_view);
        singerTextView.setText(currentWord.getmActor());

        ImageView iconView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_icon);
        iconView.setImageResource(currentWord.getImageResourceId());


        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

And here is the Actor Class

package com.example.aylin.movieapp;

import java.util.Comparator;

/**
 * Created by Aylin on 2.04.2018.
 */

```
public class Actor {
    private String mActor;
    private double mPopularity;
    private int mImageResourceId;


    public Actor(String mActor, double mPopularity, int imageResourceId){
        this.mActor = mActor;
        this.mPopularity = mPopularity;
        mImageResourceId = imageResourceId;
    }

    public String getmPopularity() {
        String pop = Double.toString(mPopularity);
        return pop; }


    public String getmActor() { return mActor; }

    public int getImageResourceId() { return mImageResourceId; }
    /*Comparator for sorting the list by roll no*/


}
```

Ignore:afdsdgjhjgkıfgdsgjhsfdhfhafdgfhkjhılşdsfhljkipşdjlhişkdsfl

Comment: where is the error and where is your MovieAdapter?

Comment: @AylinGörgün You need to better describe what you want to have as a result. Also, if you have an error, you have to better show what error it is.

Comment: This question needs to be clarified.  It says "I'm getting this error" ... but then doesn't say what the error is.   Is it a compilation error?  A runtime error (with a stacktrace)?  Is the "error" that the program is not behaving as you expect?

Comment: Just red underlined itemAdapter and says cannot resolve symbol

Comment: Can you post the code of the `Actor` class? Maybe the problem can be found there.

Comment: public class Actor {
    private String mActor;
    private double mPopularity;
    private int mImageResourceId;


    public Actor(String mActor, double mPopularity, int imageResourceId){
        this.mActor = mActor;
        this.mPopularity = mPopularity;
        mImageResourceId = imageResourceId;
    }

    public String getmPopularity() {
        String pop = Double.toString(mPopularity);
        return pop; }

    public String getmActor() { return mActor; }

    public int getImageResourceId() { return mImageResourceId; }
}

Comment: You do realize that you can edit the question to include the code in a properly formatted way?

Answer (score 0):

Just omit `(Actors.this).` entirely.

An anonymous inner class can reference all the `final` variables of the containing method.

Comment: With this way for Example in my list there is tom hanks but when I write in edit text nothing is found even with "t" or 1

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that `Actor` doesn't override `toString()`. Of course, with the sh*tty documentation of `ArrayAdapter.getFilter()`, you'd either have to guess what the returned `Filter` does, or look at the source, which is what I did, and it calls `toString()` of the items the `ArrayAdapter` is responsible for. So overriding `toString()` in `Actor` so that it returns `mActor` might solve the problem.

Comment: Can you please write it  @Override
    public String toString() {
        return mActor;
    } is this what you mean ? it didnt worked

Comment: @AylinGörgün Yes, that's what I meant. If this doesn't work, I have no idea what else the problem could be.